# How to make dependent attributes from parent class in python?

Tags: python, list, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to implement extended list class with attributes:

- size - number of elements in list
- first, last elements
- reversed list (copy of list, with reversed sequence).

If I change size attribute - initial list must be changed (slice). The same works with reversed list.

Here is my code:

```
class ExtendedList(list):
  aliases = {
        'reversed': 'R',
        'first': 'F',
        'last': 'L',
        'size': 'S'
  }

  def __init__(self, iterable):
    super().__init__(item for item in iterable)
    self.reversed = super().copy()
    self.reversed.reverse()
    self.fist = super().__getitem__(0)
    self.last = super().__getitem__(-1)
    self.size = super().__len__()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        name = self.aliases.get(name, name)
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "aliases":
            raise AttributeError
        name = self.aliases.get(name, name)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

I've added some aliases. The problem here is obvious - attributes store only **initial** values. Moreover reversed is just a copy, which isn't somehow connected with initial list. Should I rewrite all list methods to achieve required goal, or is there any trick to connect attributes with base list?

Comment: IMHO Subclassing built-ins while possible most of the time does **not** work properly. All operations return the original type, which is often an issue. They can be handy if you just need to adapt them for some specific use case, but in general I prefer delegation and manually implement operations explicitly. Also: many operations are implemented in C and do not depend on other methods. For example, in a `dict` the `setdefault` method doesn't depend on `__getitem__`, so you cannot just override a couple of "core methods" and have all of them work, you literally need to reimplement every one

Comment: Seems like inherit from ```list``` or ```dict``` is almost always painful.
https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/

Comment: In general inheriting from **any** class that wasn't designed *specifically* to be subclassed will be painful. Moreover classes defined in C have often additional issues, like calling the C functions directly instead of going through Python to call other class methods, which make them even less suitable for inheritance. So, yes that article is correct. You *can* subclass built-in types, but most of the time you should not. And when you do be prepared to reimplement almost all methods.